# How to count the number of resuts of an if on Django built in templates

Tags: python, django, django-template-filters

I have the  following situation:

```
{% for subject in subjects %}
    {% if subject.media < 60 %}
        {{ subjects|length }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The result of that is "161616", because I have 16 subjects on my database, but I want to show the number of subjects that are below the media, like "3".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do logic like that in the template. Make the query in the view

```
def my_view(request):
    num_under_60 = Subject.objects.filter(media__lt=60).count()
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'num_under_60': num_under_60})
```

then use `{{ num_under_60 }}` in the template.

Comment: This query will return the objects, you need to count them, like this:

`num_under_60 = len(Subject.object.filter(media__lt=60))`

And thank you, that worked.

Comment: Good catch, I've updated the answer to use `.count()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should write `{{ subject|length }}` instead of `{{ subjects|length }}`.